# Why Stream.CopyTo is not extension method?

Tags: .net-4.0

.NET Framework 4 introduces new helper method [Stream.CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx). It uses Read/Write methods and doesn't require access to any internal members of stream. It's not virtual and you can't override it.

So my question is why Stream.CopyTo is an instance method? It can be easily implemented as an [extension](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/12/28/stream-copyto-extension-method.aspx). Is this because Stream is an abstract class and not an interface?

It doesn't cause any issues, just interesting :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't really make much sense to create an extension method for a type for which you have the code.